# Is it advisable to use hashes as DTOs in Ruby when applying DDD?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, ruby, services, dto

It seems to me that Ruby hashes would be a good option to implement the Data Transfer Objects that the Application Services receive from the client code as commands and queries requests.

For Application Service responses, perhaps a response object with success/failure and a result property containing the data as hash.

Do you think this is a viable implementation or an anti-pattern?

Comment: What do you consider "viable?"  **Note:** don't answer that question with a tautology like "best practice."  *State your specific criteria.*

Comment: I mean, will a hash be able to accommodate to the evolution of the system, or would I be needing to replace the hash with another data structures (structs or even classes) when facing the evolving complexity of a real world application.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you think this is a viable implementation or an anti-pattern?

Using weak schemas for messages is a good idea when the consumer and provider evolve on different time scales.  There's a lot of good material out there if you want to learn in depth; Greg Young's [Versioning in an Event Sourced System](https://leanpub.com/esversioning/read) is an advanced starting point.

As a matter of clarity, you might do well to keep the concerns separate by hiding the hash *data model* behind an abstraction of what the hash is supposed to represent in this context.

For a serialization format... maybe.  During the actual *transfer*, you don't have a "hash", just a byte sequence.  So you need to be thinking about whether that byte sequence meets your needs - is it small enough, does it error correct, is it standardized well enough to be understood by all relevant endpoint implementations, and so on.

Of course, the good news is that if you keep your concerns properly separated, you can swap out different representations for transport without disturbing the rest of your app.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would encapsulate the DTO as an actual struct/object, and use the hash as an implementation detail. Perhaps the client code will pass a list parameters as a hash, and the Application Service will receive the hash and transform it into a structured DTO for usage in the aggregate methods. Is that correct?